# Validating multiple fields in an HTML form using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a signup form which is having some 12 fields. I want to validate data in those fields. First step is to check if any field is empty. One way of doing this is to get each field using Jquery and check if it is empty. I was planning to create a var array and check status of each field inside a loop using this code :

```
    var input = new Array();
    input[0]  =  $('.fullName')[0];
    input[1]  =  $('.emailID')[1];
    input[2]  =  $('.phno')[2];
    input[3]  =  $('.userName')[3];
    input[4]  =  $('.password')[4];
    input[5]  =  $('.batch')[5];
    input[6]  =  $('.nickname')[6]
    input[7]  =  $('.enrno')[7];
    input[8]  =  $('.dob')[8];
    input[9]  =  $('.fromCity')[9];
    input[10] =  $('.currcity')[10];
    input[11] =  $('.interests')[11];
    input[12] =  $('.currComp')[12];
    input[13] =  $('.currDesig')[13];
```

Now I have to run a loop to get the values and check if any field is blank.
I am writing this code for checking

```
for(i=0;i<14;i++)
    if(input[i].val()=="")
    {
        // do my work
    }
```

But the problem is that the last 15 lines of code are pointing to actual HTML DOM element, so I can't use input[i].val() directly to access the value. Any way out?

Comment: Why the `[0]` part for each jquery selector, seems like you remove that and the problems gone.

Comment: You don't need to use indexing in the jQuery selectors. You actually don't even need to create an Array to achieve this. Check @adeneo answer.

Answer (score 3):

You seriously need to just add a common class to the elements that needs validation, and then do

```
var is_valid = $('.validate_these').filter(function() {
                  return $.trim(this.value) === "";
               }).length === 0;
```

That gets all the elements with that class, and filters them based on wether or not the value is empty. If no empty elements where found, it's valid